# Auto-Implemented ReadOnly Property must provide 'Get'

Tags: vb.net, properties

Why does the Compiler complain about the following line

```
Public ReadOnly Property Name As String
```

that

> error BC30126: 'ReadOnly' property must provide a 'Get'

I thought auto-implemented readonly properties were supported in VB 14? Or am I doing something wrong here by compiling from the Commandline using `vbc.exe` delivered by the .NET Framework 4.0.30319 with Microsoft (R) Visual Basic Compiler version 14.6.1586?

Do I need to use Visual Studio to support that?

Edit: A concrete Example - shouldn't this work?

```
Class A
    Sub New(name As String)
        Me.Name = name
    End Sub
    Public ReadOnly Property Name As String
End Class
```

The above example indeed *should* work but doesn't in my case. Can someone for whom this is working please confirm that his Compilerversion is any different than mine?

Comment: The answer to the proposed duplicate clearly states that the code in this question should work with VS 2015 (you can have a ReadOnly auto-property and initialise in in the constructor). So the answer to this question is not contained in the proposed dupe.

Answer (score 1):

AutoProperties **must** be initialised.

You have to do something like this:

```
Public ReadOnly Property Name As String = "Something"
```

Or dropping the AutoProperty:

```
Public ReadOnly Property Name As String
    Get
        Return "FixedName"
    End Get
End Property
```

Or

```
Private m_Name as String = ""
Public ReadOnly Property Name As String
    Get
        Return m_Name
    End Get
End Property
```

Comment: Can't I initialize the property in the constructor?

Comment: After trying the code I just wrote I don't actually get a compilation error without the initialisation, but the property returns Nothing. Your compiler just might not like it, or my VS settings are too lax.

Comment: The normal usage of read-only autoprops is to initialize the property in the constructor - and that's fine, so long as you're using an appropriate version of VB.

Comment: @JonSkeet can you elaborate on the appropriate version of VB? What version is appropriate? Sorry, but I'm getting bitten by this all over.

Comment: @PedroRodrigues: VB14, I believe.